# Flutter - How catch back button(hardware) event?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I created Flutter app for Android. This my user case:

1. I'm on the widgetA.
2. I'm click button and and go to the widgetB. (A->B)
3. I'm click hardware back button ant return to widgetA.

   Now I'm on widgetA and I need any event so that I can update my WidgetA.
   Any advices?

Comment: Have you tried `await` your `navigator.push` or `showDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to what is called on Android `startActivityForResult()`.

If you are on `WidgetA` push a new `WidgetB` and wait for a result.

From `WidgetB` detect when the widget will pop and pop manually sending the result.

WidgetA:

```
class WidgetA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => WidgetAState();
}

class WidgetAState extends State<WidgetA> {
  Future<String> _result;

  Future<String> _startWidgetForResult(BuildContext context) async {
    String result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => WidgetB(context: context),
      ),
    );
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_right),
        onPressed: () => _result = _startWidgetForResult(context),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _result,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.data}'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

WidgetB:

```
class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  final BuildContext context;

  WidgetB({this.context});

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop("New data");
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_left),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop("New data"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text('Press back to send new data')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can wrap your widgetB in [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget. Or you can set a key press handler with `SystemChannels.keyEvent.setMessageHandler(...)`, but this isn't a recommended way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RouteObserver for that
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html